# Python: What date/time is it in NYC? (without pytz)

Tags: python

In Python, I want a Python program to be able to determine the current date and time in NYC . Is that practical?  While  datetime.datetime.now() can tell me the local time, and datetime.utcnow() can tell me the UTC (GMT). However just looking at the difference will not help me as DST changes.

I try things like "dt=datetime.now() " and "dt.timetuple()"
I get tm_isdst=-1 even if I change the computer date.

I change my computer clock from a January date to a July date. I still get tm_isdst=-1

Why not use pytz? I want the users to not have to go thru the step of downloading an extra library.

Comment: I believe `datetime` automatically takes care of DST.

Comment: What do you mean about making users download the library? pytz is MIT-licensed and I'm pretty sure you can just drop it into a directory in your code.

Comment: Also, pytz can be automatically pulled as a dependency when doing a proper install of your Python module.

Comment: @Herohtar, datetime relies on the tzinfo class to take care of DST, but the base install doesn't contain any implementations of tzinfo.

Comment: Thanks. I did not realize it was that easy. This is for a financial application where I would like the user's to be able to at least look it over. So the more I provide, the more they would have to inspect in theory. Who am I kidding. Reading other people's code can be hard, expecially when they used regex, as I am doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect some sort of problems in your use of the [datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#module-datetime), [time](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html), etc. modules, but without knowing more, not much help can be provided.

The following suggestion has some definite drawbacks, and I really recommend more pursuit to solving the problems with datetime, etc.  However, if you're sure to have a web connection and need to get something done fast, you could query [USNO time](http://www.usno.navy.mil/USNO/time) with something like:

```
import urllib
f = urllib.urlopen("http://tycho.usno.navy.mil/cgi-bin/timer.pl")
time_page = f.readlines()
for line in time_page:
    if line.find("Eastern Time") != -1:
        ny_time = line[4:24]
        break
print ny_time
```

The output looks like:

> Jan. 19, 05:18:04 PM

This makes use of the fact that NYC is in the Eastern Time zone.  Also, it assumes the USNO server is available to your user.  Furthermore, it has assumptions about the format of the content returned.  I don't know if/how frequently that format changes.  Also, if this is going to be used a lot, please find another server, as you don't want to sink the USNO server!  (Pun not originally intended, but recognized and kept. :-).

Comment: That's an interesting idea. Having internet access is intrinsic, so I might consider that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not in the same timezone as NYC, it's in practice impossible without knowing the timezone and when DST changes. You can't hardcode it for NYC, of course, but it is way easier to just install pytz or dateutil, and then you aren't limited to NYC.

Comment: Thanks folks. I will think about which way to go. This has been very useful. Thanks.